# Add array of other records from the same table to each record

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

My project is a Latin language learning app. My DB has all the words I'm teaching, in the table 'words'. It has the *lemma* (the main form of the word), along with the definition and other information the user needs to learn.

I show one word at a time for them to guess/remember what it means. The correct word is shown along with some wrong words, like:

- What does *Romanus* mean? Greek - /Roman/ - Phoenician - barbarian
- What does *domus* mean? /house/ - horse - wall - senator

The wrong options are randomly drawn from the same table, and must be from the same part of speech (adjective, noun...) as the correct word; but I am only interested in their lemma. My return value looks like this (some properties omitted):

```
[
  { lemma: 'Romanus', definition: 'Roman', options: ['Greek', 'Phoenician', 'barbarian'] },
  { lemma: 'domus', definition: 'house', options: ['horse', 'wall', 'senator'] }
]
```

What I am looking for is a more efficient way of doing it than my current approach, which runs a new query for each word:

```
// All the necessary requires are here

class Word extends Model {
  static async fetch() {
    const words = await this.findAll({
      limit: 10,
      order: [Sequelize.literal('RANDOM()')],
      attributes: ['lemma', 'definition'],    // also a few other columns I need
    });
    const wordsWithOptions = await Promise.all(words.map(this.addOptions.bind(this)));
    return wordsWithOptions;
  }

  static async addOptions(word) {
    const options = await this.findAll({
      order: [Sequelize.literal('RANDOM()')],
      limit: 3,
      attributes: ['lemma'],
      where: {
        partOfSpeech: word.dataValues.partOfSpeech,
        lemma: { [Op.not]: word.dataValues.lemma },
      },
    });
    return { ...word.dataValues, options: options.map((row) => row.dataValues.lemma) };
  }
}
```

So, is there a way I can do this with raw SQL? How about Sequelize? One thing that still helps me is to give a name to what I'm trying to do, so that I can Google it.

---

EDIT: I have tried the following and at least got somewhere:

```
const words = await this.findAll({
  limit: 10,
  order: [Sequelize.literal('RANDOM()')],
  attributes: {
    include: [[sequelize.literal(`(
      SELECT lemma FROM words AS options
      WHERE "partOfSpeech" = "options"."partOfSpeech"
      ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
    )`), 'options']],
  },
});
```

Now, there are two problems with this. First, I only get one option, when I need three; but if the query has `LIMIT 3`, I get: `SequelizeDatabaseError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.

The second error is that while the code above does return something, it always gives the same word as an option! I thought to remedy that with `WHERE "partOfSpeech" = "options"."partOfSpeech"`, but then I get `SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "words"`.

So, how do I tell PostgreSQL "for each row in the result, add a column with an array of three lemmas, `WHERE existingRow.partOfSpeech = wordToGoInTheArray.partOfSpeech?`"

Answer (score 0):

**Revised**  
Well that seems like a different question and perhaps should be posted that way, but... 

The main technique remains the same. JOIN instead of sub-select. The difference being generating the list of lemmas for then piping then into the initial query. In a single this can get nasty.
As single statement (actually this turned out not to be too bad):

```
select w.lemma, w.defination, string_to_array(string_agg(o.defination,','), ',') as options
 from words  w 
 join lateral 
      (select defination  
         from words o 
        where o.part_of_speech = w.part_of_speech
          and o.lemma != w.lemma
         order by random()
         limit 3
      ) o on 1=1 
  where w.lemma in( select lemma 
                      from words
                     order by random() 
                     limit 4           --<<< replace with parameter
                  )  
  group by  w.lemma, w.defination;
```

The other approach build a small SQL function to randomly select a specified number of lemmas. This selection is the piped into the (renamed) function previous fiddle.

```
create or replace 
function exam_lemma_definition_options(lemma_array_in text[])
 returns table (lemma  text 
               ,definition text 
               ,option text[]
               )
  language sql strict  
as $$
  select w.lemma, w.definition, string_to_array(string_agg(o.definition,','), ',') as options
    from words  w 
    join lateral 
         (select definition
            from words o 
           where o.part_of_speech = w.part_of_speech
             and o.lemma != w.lemma
            order by random()
           limit 3
         ) o on 1=1 
   where w.lemma = any(lemma_array_in)
   group by  w.lemma, w.definition;
$$;  


create or replace 
function  exam_lemmas(num_of_lemmas integer) 
 returns text[]
 language sql 
 strict
as $$
    select string_to_array(string_agg(lemma,','),',')
      from (select lemma 
              from words
             order by random() 
             limit num_of_lemmas
           ) ll
$$;
```

Using this approach your calling code reduces to a needs a single SQL statement:

```
select * 
  from exam_lemma_definition_options(exam_lemmas(4))
order by lemma;
```

This permits you to specify the numbers of lemmas to select (in this case 4) limited only by the number of rows in Words table. See revised [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=daf3331e6b5c4e89118902e3355fa6cb).

**Original**  
Instead of using a sub-select to get the option words just JOIN.

```
select w.lemma, w.definition, string_to_array(string_agg(o.definition,','), ',') as options
  from words  w 
  join lateral 
       (select definition  
          from words o 
         where o.part_of_speech = w.part_of_speech
           and o.lemma != w.lemma
          order by random()
          limit 3
       ) o on 1=1 
where w.lemma = any(array['Romanus', 'domus'])
group by  w.lemma, w.definition;
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=317cd45485c36e192a205529be799de5). Obviously this will not necessary produce the same options as your questions provides due to random() selection. But it will get matching parts of speech. I will leave translation to your source language to you; or you can use the function option and reduce your SQL to a simple "select *".

Comment: How do I do this without hard-coding values? My table has about 1500 entries. For whatever 10 entries get randomly selected, I want to find three options belonging to the same part of speech as each of them.

Comment: See **revised** section in answer.